# NoClassDefFoundError on Android 2.1 only, using Guava Library

Tags: java, android, guava, noclassdeffounderror

I wrote an Android app that use the Guava library.

The app works perfectly fine on Android 4 (virtual machine and real device).

However, when I try to launch the app on a virtual machine running Android 2.1, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedMap
```

I have played with the libraries imports. The idea behind: older version of Android might handle jars in a different way. No success here.

It is worth mentioning, that the app is an update of a previous version already using Guava. The previous version worked fine on all devices, but wasn't using the ImmutableSortedMap object rather just an ImmutableList.
Would it be possible that the phone is loading his own version of the Guava library (that might not contains ImmutableSortedMap)?

I am using Eclipse with ADT 20. Here is how my libraries looks like in Eclipse package explorer:

[image: Eclipse package explorer.]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you check those checkboxes in the java build path wizard?

Comment: Yes, I try checking and unchecking them. No changes :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to be using the [guava-jdk5 back port](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava-jdk5).  In newer versions of Guava, `ImmutableSortedMap` implements `NavigableMap`, which was introduced in JDK6.  `NavigableMap` is not supported in earlier versions of Android -- specifically including 2.1; `NavigableMap` was released on Android as of Android 2.3 Gingerbread, it looks like.

(In the backport, `ImmutableSortedMap` supports all the `NavigableMap` methods; it just doesn't actually implement `NavigableMap`.)

Comment: Thanks for your help and kudo for the work of the Google Core Java Libraries team!