# Android 2.2 : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for Guava classes

Tags: android, guava, android-2.2-froyo, android-gradle-plugin, android-guava

I'm getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.collect.SortedMultisets$NavigableElementSet` on **Android 2.2** devices.

I'm getting the same crash on Android 2.2 emulator

I'm not getting that error on **Android 4.x** devices though.

My `build.gradle` has:

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '15.0'
}

defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
}
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use newer version of Guava (which you should), [use Guava JDK5 backport](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava-jdk5) (it will work with Android 2.2). Also, see [this answer explaining what's going on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13347613/708434) (some classes/interfaces Guava uses are not supported in Android 2.1-2.2).

Note that currently there's no guava-jdk5-15.0 release (and it probably won't be) but guava-jdk5-16.0 is on its way [(see comments in this G+ post)](https://plus.google.com/118010414872916542489/posts/hk8bpXQyjLi).

Comment: I'm not sure about the reliability of that port. Is it something that also comes from Google or otherwise something reliable?

Comment: Yes, the JDK5 backport comes from, and is supported by Google.

Comment: @Alex Guava JDK5 backport 16.0-**rc1** is now available - [see the announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/guava-announce/RiiMam7VvSc/d9QtJmPV_mwJ).

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer  here http://porcupineprogrammer.blogspot.com/2013/06/guava-and-minsdkversion.html.

Turns out only Guava 13 and earlier work properly with Android 2.2.

I've downgraded to Guava 13.